# What is the proper way to write/read a file with different IO streams

Tags: java, file-io, iostream, inputstream, outputstream

I have a file that contains bytes, chars, and an object, all of which need to be written then read.  What would be the best way to utilize Java's different IO streams for writing and reading these data types?

More specifically, is there a proper way to add delimiters and recognize those delimiters, then triggering what stream should be used?  I believe I need some clarification on using multiple streams in the same file, something I have never studied before.  A thorough explanation would be a sufficient answer.

Comment: Could you read the whole file as a byte stream, then find your delimiters in there, put the parts into byte arrays and read those as the respective streams?

Comment: That may work up until the object that needs to be read, but I feel there might be a more direct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **EJP** already suggested, use ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream an0d wrap your other elements as an object(s). I'm giving as an answer so I could show an example (it's hard to do it in comment) EJP - if you want to embed it in your question, please do and I'll delete the answer.

```
class MyWrapedData implements serializeable{
    private String string1;
    private String string2;
    private char   char1;
    // constructors
    // getters setters
}
```

Write to file:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
out.writeObject(myWrappedDataInstance);
out.flush();
```

Read from file

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
Object obj = in.readObject();
MyWrapedData wraped = null;
if ((obj != null) && (obj instanceof MyWrappedData))
    wraped = (MyWrapedData)obj;
// get the specific elements from the wraped object
```

see very clear example here: [Read](http://www.javadb.com/reading-objects-from-file-using-objectinputstream) and [Write](http://www.javadb.com/writing-objects-to-file-with-objectoutputstream)

Comment: This is a good example of how to read and write objects, but it fails to address the fact that I also have primitives in the file that have to be differentiated from the object.

Comment: @Trevor Arjeski - It is exactly what it shows - You wrap the primitives in an object of "MyWrapedData". I included only Strings and char, bur it could be any other primitive as well. The you save the object that wraps them in a file, later you read the object and extract the primitives in the same way.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't even look at the object.  Now I get it! Thanks

Comment: would it be possible to put an object inside the wrappedData object?

Comment: @Trevor - sure, the same way you put any other object in a class.

Answer (score 1):

Redesign the file. There is no sensible way of implementing it as presently designed. For example the object presupposes an ObjectOutputStream, which has a header - where's that going to go? And how are you going to know where to switch from bytes to chars?

I would probably use an ObjectOutputStream for the whole thing and write everything as objects. Then Serialization solves all those problems for you. After all you don't actually care what's in the file, only how to read and write it.

Comment: So I dump everything in the file as an object how will I read it back in?

Comment: @Trevor Arjeski Write with writeObject(), read with readObject() and cast to byte[], char[], your class, etc. Couldn't be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the structure of the file? It is unclear because the first sentence of your question contradicts being able to add delineators. If you **can** change the file structure you could output the different data types into separate files. I would consider this the 'proper' way to delineate the data streams.

If you are stuck with the file the way it is then you will need to write an interface to the file's structure which in practice is a shopping list of read operations and a lot of exception handling. A hackish way to program because it will require a hex editor and a lot of trial and error but it works in certain cases.

Comment: My mistake, I do have control over the structure of the file

Answer (score 0):

Why not write the file as XML, possibly with a nice simple library like XSTream. If you are concerned about space, wrap it in gzip compression.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the file format, and it's not an exceptionally large file (i.e. < 1 GiB), have you thought about using Google's Protocol Buffers?

They generate code that parses (and serializes) file/byte[] content. Protocol buffers use a tagging approach on every value that includes (1) field number and (2) a type, so they have nice properties such as forward/backward compatability with optional fields etc. They are fairly well optimized for both speed and file size, adding only ~2 bytes of overhead for a short byte[], with ~2-4 additional bytes to encode the length on larger byte[] fields (VarInt encoded lengths).

This could be overkill, but if you have a bunch of different fields & types, protobuf is really helpful. See: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/.

An alternative is Thrift by Facebook, with support for a few more languages although possibly less use in the wild last I checked.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of your file is not fixed, consider using a wrapper per type. First you need to create the interface of your wrapper classes….

```
interface MyWrapper extends Serializable {
    void accept(MyWrapperVisitor visitor);
}
```

Then you create the MyWrapperVisitor interface…

```
interface MyWrapperVisitor {
    void visit(MyString wrapper);
    void visit(MyChar wrapper);
    void visit(MyLong wrapper);
    void visit(MyCustomObject wrapper);
}
```

Then you create your wrapper classes…

```
class MyString implements MyWrapper {
    public final String value;

    public MyString(String value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(MyWrapperVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);

    }
}
.
.
.
```

And finally you read your objects…

```
final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(myfile);
final ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(in);
final MyWrapperVisitor visitor = new MyWrapperVisitor() {
    @Override
    public void visit(MyString wrapper) {
        //your logic here

    }
    .
    .
    .
};

//loop over all your objects here
final MyWrapper wrapper = (MyWrapper) objIn.readObject();
wrapper.accept(visitor);
```